# Excluir fines de semana de un rango de fechas Python

Tags: python, datetime

Necesito saltar los fines de semana. En mi codigo realizo una conversion de una fecha en str a datetime, luego ingreso la cantidad de dias que quiero sumar.
Lo que busco es que en la variable fin esten excluidos los fines de semana.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

inicio = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2009', '%d/%m/%Y')
fin = inicio + datetime.timedelta(+2500)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para filtrar las fechas puedes usar el atributo [`weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) que retorna el día de la semana (Lunes es 0 y Domingo es 6) y comprobar que sea menor a 5 o [`isoweekday`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) (Lunes es 1 y Domingo es 7) y comprobar que sea menor de 6:

```
inicio = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2009', '%d/%m/%Y')
dias = 2500

dates = []
for days in range(dias):
    date = inicio + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    if date.weekday() < 5:
        dates.append(date)
```

Si ya tienes una lista de fechas y quieres excluir las que son fines de samana la idea es la misma:

```
import datetime

fechas = [datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 19),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 20),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 21),
          datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 22)]

fechas_lab = [fecha for fecha in fechas if fecha.weekday() < 5]
```

> ```
> >>> fechas_lab
> [datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 22, 0, 0)]
> ```

No obstante, te recomiendo usar pandas para genera le rango de fechas, por ejemplo puedes conseguir lo que deseas  con [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) usando como periodo "B" (business day) o directamente con `pandas.bdate_range`:

```
import pandas as pd

inicio = pd.datetime.strptime('01/01/2009', '%d/%m/%Y')
dt = pd.bdate_range(start=inicio, periods=dias, freq="D")
```

Puedes usar una fecha como limite también:

```
import pandas as pd

inicio = pd.datetime.strptime('01/01/2009', '%d/%m/%Y')
fin = pd.datetime.strptime('01/01/2011', '%d/%m/%Y')

dt = pd.bdate_range(start=inicio, end=fin, freq="D")
```

Un ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

inicio = pd.datetime.strptime('19/07/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')
fin = pd.datetime.strptime('31/07/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')

dt = pd.bdate_range(start=inicio, end=fin)
```

> ```
> >>> dt
>
> DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-19', '2019-07-22', '2019-07-23', '2019-07-24',
>                '2019-07-25', '2019-07-26', '2019-07-29', '2019-07-30',
>                '2019-07-31'],
>               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
> ```

Como se puede aprecia no están el 20, 21, 27 y 28.

Si no queremos usarlo como índice podemos obtener una Serie, una array NumPy, una lista, etc usando los métodos `to_series()`, `to_numpy()`, `to_list()`, etc.

> ```
> >>> dt.to_numpy()
>
> array(['2019-07-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-07-22T00:00:00.000000000',
>        '2019-07-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-07-24T00:00:00.000000000',
>        '2019-07-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-07-26T00:00:00.000000000',
>        '2019-07-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-07-30T00:00:00.000000000',
>        '2019-07-31T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
> ```

Si lo que quiere es filtrar datos ya existentes tienes múltiples opciones.

Si tienes un DataFrame con DateTimeIndex como índice o una serie temporal quieres quedarte solo con los días laborables puedes hacer uso del método `asfreq`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"fecha": (pd.datetime(2019, 7, 19),
                             pd.datetime(2019, 7, 20),
                             pd.datetime(2019, 7, 21),
                             pd.datetime(2019, 7, 22)
                             ),
                   "col_dummy": (1, 2, 3, 5)
                  })

df.set_index("fecha", inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>              col_dummy
> fecha 
> 2019-07-19   1
> 2019-07-20   2
> 2019-07-21   3
> 2019-07-22   5
>
> >>> df.asfreq(pd.tseries.offsets.BDay())
>
>              col_dummy
> fecha
> 2019-07-19   1
> 2019-07-22   5
> ```

Si no es un índice, sino una serie o columna de tipo `datetime` puedes filtrar de varias formas, por ejemplo usando el mismo método que con `datetime` en Python estándar:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"fecha": (pd.datetime(2019, 7, 19),
                             pd.datetime(2019, 7, 20),
                             pd.datetime(2019, 7, 21),
                             pd.datetime(2019, 7, 22)
                             ),
                   "col_dummy": (1, 2, 3, 5)
                  })
```

> ```
> >>> df
>         fecha  col_dummy
> 0  2019-07-19          1
> 1  2019-07-20          2
> 2  2019-07-21          3
> 3  2019-07-22          5
>
> >>> df.loc[df["fecha"].dt.weekday < 5]
>
>         fecha  col_dummy
> 1  2019-07-19          1
> 3  2019-07-22          5
> ```

o usando el atributo `pd.datetime.dt.weekday_name`junto a `isin`

> ```
> >>> df.loc[~df["fecha"].dt.weekday_name.isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])]
> ```

Comment: okey y usando pandas  como excluyo los fines de semana?

Comment: El ejemplo que te pongo ya genera un `DatetimeIndex` con solo los dias laborables, si quieres una serie puedes usar el método `to_series()`, (`pd.bdate_range(start=inicio, end=fin).to_series()`) o `to_numpy()` para un array de numpy, etc...